# Selector for n-th and m-th sibling element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

With CSS3, I want to grab exactly the first and the forth sibling elements - and only these two. Couldn't find a working `:nth-of-type(an+b)` selector, as I'm not after *every* a-th element but am only looking for the very two elements.

```
:nth-of-type(1), // :first-of-type wouldn't work either,
:nth-of-type(4){
  ...
}
```

won't work, as the latter selector sort of overrides the first selector. There seems to be a last nth-of-type selector wins approach in effect.

How can I select both, the first and the fourth sibling element with CSS3?

Comment: That seems to work fine, given an actual element. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ou5won6k/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `:nth-of-type`, it needs type or class, like `div:nth-of-type` or `.block:nth-of-type`.

```css
div:nth-of-type(1),
div:nth-of-type(4){
  color: lime;
}

.block:nth-of-type(1),
.block:nth-of-type(4){
  color: red;
}

/*  for styling purpose  */
div + span { margin-top: 20px; }
.block { display: block; }
```

```html
<div>Hey there div</div>
<div>Hey there div</div>
<div>Hey there div</div>
<div>Hey there div</div>
<div>Hey there div</div>

<span class="block">Hey there div</span>
<span class="block">Hey there div</span>
<span class="block">Hey there div</span>
<span class="block">Hey there div</span>
<span class="block">Hey there div</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector that you post seems to work ok

```css
div:nth-of-type(1),
div:nth-of-type(4){
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
```

If you want to get it done in just one selector, this would be it

The first element select (for n = 0) is the fourth, then the first, and then we go to negative numbers

```css
div:nth-of-type(-3n+4){
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
```